# Handling success/error response messages in React Apollo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo

I'd like to have a success/error message displayed after mutations take place to inform the user that their mutation was/wasn't successful.

I'm coming from a Redux background where this was easy - I'd make a `<Response />` component which would sit somewhere globally on the app (for example, near the root of the app so it will be on all screens), and this component would be connected to the Redux store so any messages dispatched would cause the response component to appear.

With Apollo, I'm not sure the best way to do this. Let's say I have a todo app which has the following component structure:

- ResponseComponent (parent - elsewhere on the app - I want this to receive the response message from the AddTodoComponent mutation)
- TodoComponent (parent)

  - AddTodoComponent (child)
  - ViewTodos (child)

I'm approaching it so the mutation for adding the todo would be placed in the `AddTodoComponent` component and the query for querying the todos will be in the `ViewTodos` component. The list automatically updates because of the `update()` call in the mutation, but how would I then send a response message to be shown elsewhere in the app?

I've explored making a HoC which works well for showing a response message for the immediate component which the mutation is actioned from, but this will not work if the component calling the mutation is multiple component levels deep. I've also thought about doing the standard React way and passing up function callbacks up through the component tree, but this seems like a code smell to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global error handling is pretty straight-forward with `react-apollo`. Displaying success messages isn't as much.

**For errors:**

Apollo allows you to provide an `onError` callback when initializing your client. If you are using `apollo-boost`, then this is as simple as providing the `onError` option. The callback receives a few parameters, including `graphQLErrors`, which contains the errors included with the graphQL response. You can check for its presence, and then display errors appropriately.

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI}/api/v0`,
  credentials: 'include',
  clientState: {
    resolvers,
    defaults
  },
  onError: ({ graphQLErrors, networkError, response }) => {
    if (graphQLErrors) {
      // Do something with the errors
    } else if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401) {
      // This also causes a browser refresh, which clears the cache.
      window.location = '/login';
    }
  },
});
```

If you are not using `apollo-boost`, then you will need to use [apollo-link-error](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/error-handling.html#network).

**For Success:**

I haven't figured out a way to handle this globally yet. In the mean time, the `Mutation` component accepts an `onCompleted` prop for when the request finishes successfully. The callback is passed the graphQL response as its argument, so if you include a success message in the response, you could use it with something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  onCompleted(resp) {
    // Display using resp.message
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Mutation mutation={ MUTATION } onCompleted={ this.onCompleted }>
        {(doMutation) => (
          doMutation({ variables: { a: b } })
        )}
      </Mutation>
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone has a better way for handling global success messages, I would love to hear it.

Comment: I am trying to use ```onCompleted={setStatus(true)}``` in Typescript and it says ```Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((data: any) => void) | undefined'.ts(2322)```

Comment: @x89 I'm not sure what your `setStatus` looks like, but you'll need to change its signature to match the expected signature. So have setStatus return a function that returns void, instead of having it return void itself.